# Erro ao abrir Ionic App

Tags: ionic

Criei um projeto em branco em Ionic, e ao mandar rodá-lo com o comando "ionic server", ele apresenta o erro abaixo.
Nada foi mexido no projeto original.

Typescript Error
Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable 'process' must be of type '{ env: { [key: string]: string; }; }', but here has type 'Process'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts
interface NodeRequire extends NodeRequireFunction {
    resolve(id: string): string;
    cache: any;
Ionic Framework: 3.9.2
Ionic App Scripts: 3.2.0
Angular Core: 5.2.11
Angular Compiler CLI: 5.2.11
Node: 10.8.0
OS Platform: Linux 4.15
Navigator Platform: Linux x86_64
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite companheiro!
Tente executar `npm install`. As vezes esse erro pode ser por conta de dependências não instaladas.

Se mesmo assim não tiver progresso, execute os comandos abaixo:

```
# desinstalar ionic na pasta do projeto
npm uninstall --save ionic
# instalando globalmente
npm install -g ionic
# run
ionic serve -c
```

Apoio: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3541

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que você escreveu, seria **ionic serve** e não **ionic server**
Se caso você só tenha escrevido errado aqui, tente o seguinte:

- `yarn remove ionic` ou `npm uninstall -g ionic`
- `npm cache clean` se não funcionar, user a flag **--force**
- `yarn global add ionic` ou `npm install -g ionic`